# Modifiable Tree Implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have created a tree structure, similar to the below image.Initially each node contains certain set of numbers.

When a child is added to a node, intersection of the child's set of numbers and parent's set of numbers is stored in the child. Finally the parent node has a set which is basically union of all the sets of the child sets (Any numbers which don't fall under any of the child will be removed).

In order to do this, I have stored all the numbers in a List (in the Tree class) and gave each node two indices (leftIndex, rightIndex) to identify its own set of numbers from the List. (Eg. In the below tree, list contains 21 numbers and Node A contains 14 numbers which are 0 to 13 in the list)

[image: Tree Structure]

Node Structure :

```
public class Node<T> {
    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    private Node<T> parent = null;
    private T data = null;

    public Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent){
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren(){
        return  children;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child){
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return (this.parent == null);
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return this.children.size() == 0;
    }

    public void removeParent() {
        this.parent = null;
    }

    public Node() {
    }
}
```

NodeData :

```
public class NodeData{

    private int leftIndex;
    private int rightIndex;
    private int level;
}
```

Tree Structure :

```
public class Tree<V>{
    private String[] parameters;
    private String[][] parameterValues;
    private int height;
    private Node<V> root;
    private List<Long> aggregatedNumbersList = new ArrayList<>();//contains all the leaf node numbers 
    private List<Node<NodeData>> leafNodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now, based on above tree I want to create the below tree. In the below tree levels of nodes are modified, but the list of the numbers remains the same. Each hierarchy contains the same set of numbers as that of the above tree (Eg. Node A,Node C pair contains a set of four numbers).

So, how can I create a dynamic tree where levels can be modified and any new node can be added.

[image: Modified Tree Structure]

Comment: Not my downvote, but this sounds like you are asking for a full implementation here, but you did not show any effort in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I created a mapping between the hierarchies and the corresponding set of numbers. But this turns out to be huge, since the hierarchies keep on increasing as the number of nodes at each level increases.